# If $X$ follows binomial distribution $B(n,p)$ with $p=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$, what is the expectation of $\sqrt{X}$.

Tags: expected-value, binomial-distribution

I recently ran into this problem. $X$ follows binomial distribution $B(n,p)$ with $p=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$. I don't know how to calculate $E\left[\sqrt{X}\right]$. I don't need to find out the exact answer, but I need to find out how it relates to $O\left(\sqrt[4]{n}\right)$.

I'm sorry I didn't give my previous attempts. In fact I am trying to solve for the value of $\sum_{x=1}^{N/2}\tbinom{N/2}{x}(1/\sqrt{N})^x(1-1/\sqrt{N})^{N/2-x}\sqrt{x/n}=\sqrt{1/N}E(\sqrt{x})$. I have tried to try to find this value by solving for $E(x)$. So I get：
$$E(\sqrt{x})=\sum_{x=1}^{N/2}{\sqrt{\frac{N}{4x}}\tbinom{N/2-1}{x-1}(1/\sqrt{n})^{x-1}(1-1/\sqrt{n})^{N/2-x}}$$
It is difficult for me to further calculate the value of this equation, so I tried to discover the relationship between this value and $O\left(\sqrt[4]{n}\right)$. I let $x=N^{1/4}$. I get:
$${\sqrt{\frac{N}{4N^{1/4}}}\tbinom{N/2-1}{N^{1/4}-1}(1/\sqrt{n})^{N^{1/4}-1}(1-1/\sqrt{n})^{N/2-N^{1/4}}}$$
I try to use Stirling's approximation to calculate $\tbinom{N/2-1}{N^{1/4}-1}$, but here is still no way to simplify $(1-1/\sqrt{n})^{N/2-N^{1/4}}$ with $\tbinom{N/2-1}{N^{1/4}-1}$.

So I was wondering if this expectation had been solved before, but I didn't find anything about it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In this question $p$ is a function of $n$ instead of being constant (in your linked example). So perhaps this is where the OP’s confusion is coming from @JeanMarie

Comment: @FD_bfa You are right. I erase this misleading "similar" question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Note that questions consisting in a problem statement with no attempt at solving it or additional context 
are discouraged and generally poorly received, so it's best for you to edit your post and add some more of your thoughts on this problem. By the way, if you're stuck, this should get you started : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to show that $\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X}] = O(n^{1/4})$, then since $\mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X}]^2 = \text{Var}[\sqrt{X}] \ge 0$, we have that $\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X}] \le \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X]} = \sqrt{n \cdot \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} = n^{1/4}$.

This is enough to show that $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[X]} = O(n^{1/4})$, but if you also want a crude lower bound, that can be done as well:

Since the median of a $B(n,p)$ distribution is either $\lfloor np \rfloor$ or $\lceil np \rceil$, we have that $\mathbb{P}[X \ge \lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor] \ge \dfrac{1}{2}$. Hence, $$\begin{align*}\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X}] &= \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\mathbb{P}[X = k]\sqrt{k} \\ &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor - 1}\mathbb{P}[X = k]\sqrt{k} + \sum_{\lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor}^{n}\mathbb{P}[X = k]\sqrt{k} \\ &\ge \sum_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor - 1}\mathbb{P}[X = k] \cdot 0 + \sum_{\lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor}^{n}\mathbb{P}[X = k] \cdot \sqrt{\lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor} \\ &= \mathbb{P}[X \ge \lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor] \cdot \sqrt{\lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor} \\ &\ge \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor}\end{align*}$$

Therefore, $\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\lfloor n^{1/2} \rfloor} \le \mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X}] \le n^{1/4}$.

We can probably get a stronger lower bound on $\mathbb{E}[\sqrt{X}]$ by using [tail bounds for the binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_bounds).